# Karate contains only any of given options

Tags: karate

I am trying to achieve following

```
[
    {
        "f1": "v1",
        "x": "A"
    },
    {
        "f1": "q1",
        "x": "B"
    }
]
```

I am iterating over an array of objects where I have a `x` field

x can be value **A,B or C** only any one of these.

This I could not write in karate as it throws error.
I tried contains any and contains only

`contains any` allows any other value outside given 3.
`contains only` does not work when i have just A and B

trying to form this condition correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible solution:

```
* def response = 
"""
[
  {
    "f1": "v1",
    "x": "A"
  },
  {
    "f1": "q1",
    "x": "B"
  }
]
"""
* def isValid = function(x){ return x == 'A' || x == 'B' || x == 'C' }
* def schema = { f1: '#string', x: '#? isValid(_)' }
* match each response == schema
```

It may be simpler to transform the JSON into a form easier to validate. Also I'm showing how to use regex validation:

```
* def values = response.map(x => x.x)
* match each values == '#regex [A-C]'
```